# Disabling a specific C# 9 source generator

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, sourcegenerators

Is there any way to disable a specific C# 9 source generator? Or alternatively disable them all?

the package in question is https://github.com/Husqvik/GraphQlClientGenerator#c-9-source-generator which is mean to be able to be used as both a lib and a source generator. but those are mutually exclusive, ie the majority of use cases it make no sense to gen code both by executing code and by code gen

Comment: Pretty sure source generators are just fancy analyzers, and you can disable those.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Let’s ask a maintainer of several very important open-source projects (and with reasonable rep) if he has made an effort.

Comment: @DanielA.White i spent ~45 min researching. nothing that even gave me a direction of what to try.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman i tried a few diff combos of exclude/include. the generator still ran. eg
IncludeAssets="compile"  ExcludeAssets="all"

Comment: Is the source generation a standalone package or part of another package?

Comment: @JohanP it is a lib and a source generator in one package. i updated the Q with the full context

Comment: I think the generator needs to be included as an analyzer dependency... If it's being included as a transitive dependency, complain upstream or recompile packages yourself I guess.

Comment: Or can you "ExcludeAssets" the transitive analyzers dependency https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman ExcludeAssets didnt work for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

seems this will disable all

```xml
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" 
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

removing a named one uses the file path

```xml
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers"
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="D:\nugets\nugetx\0.9.2\analyzers\dotnet\cs\NugetXAnalizer.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

ok and finally u can remove based on filename

```xml
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers"
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)"
              Condition="'%(Filename)' == 'NugetXAnalizer'"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Hi, Where do add the target ? How Do I integrate the target into my solution ? Thx

Comment: I added the target into my Directory.Build.targets file. If you don't have one you can create that file in your project or solution folder. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022

Comment: I wanted to use the third flavor, to remove based on filename. But what worked for me was just a bit different. For the condition I had to use Analyzer.Filename instead of just Filename. E.g.

<Target Name="DisableAnalyzers" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)" Condition="'%(Analyzer.Filename)' == 'NugetXAnalizer'"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>